# Retrying Create Folder Errors on Google Drive

Tags: python, django, api, google-drive-api

I've been working on an Django app that will create a given folder structure in Google Drive. The problem I have been having is that sometimes the request I make to create a folder in Drive fails.

( The error that is being raised is an 'SSLError Read Operation Timed Out', I'm using version 1.1 of 'google-api-python-client' library to make the request )

I've implemented the binary backoff retrying that Google suggest in the Drive Docs to handle errors but it seems this will lead to the creation of the same folder twice

( Binary Backoff link: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors )

So say I try to create folder 'demo', this request fails. I wait, then retry. The second request now creates another folder called 'demo 1' as the original folder is in drive. It seems that even though there is an error sometimes the request goes though.

I've created a fix that in the event a create fails it will look in Google Drive to see if the folder has been created. That seem's to stop the issue from happening but can make the application a bit slow.

My question is has anyone experienced this and what would be the best way to handle this error. Perhaps I should not implement binary backoff at all and just assume every create will succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this. It's a known Drive bug.

I can't think of a better solution than yours. Just a word of warning, because it's possible to have multiple folders with the same name, you should probably check on title plus createdDate to avoid false positives.

Comment: Thats a good point, especially if I'm creating in a folder that already has some stuff in it.